# Let users know my website uses cookies and local storage on site to comply with GDPR

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I know how to use cookies and local storage but i'm not sure when I am allowed to.

I'm making a small quiz website where people can create questions with multiple choice answers, users will are able to authenticate by creating accounts, the authentication and storing questions on a database are being managed by [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).
I am using html, javascript and css, no backend languages.

I have searched on the web and [this website by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) explains a bit about the regulations around cookies, here is the part about regulations.

> Legislation or regulations that cover the use of cookies include:
>
> The General Data Privacy Regulation (GDPR) in the European Union The
> ePrivacy Directive in the EU The California Consumer Privacy Act These
> regulations have global reach, because they apply to any site on the
> World Wide Web that is accessed by users from these jurisdictions (the
> EU and California, with the caveat that California's law applies only
> to entities with gross revenue over 25 million USD, among other
> things.)
>
> These regulations include requirements such as:
>
> Notifying users that your site uses cookies. Allowing users to opt out
> of receiving some or all cookies. Allowing users to use the bulk of
> your service without receiving cookies. There may be other regulations
> governing the use of cookies in your locality. The burden is on you to
> know and comply with these regulations. There are companies that offer
> "cookie banner" code that helps you comply with these regulations.

I have tried (as they have suggested) to get a cookie banner from a company but it doesn't have anything to do with local storage and I don't know if this is an issue or not.
Also I think firebase might be using analytics on my website, so I should be notifying my users of traking.
Here is an image of the cookie banner
[Cookie banner on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNBN5.png)

This is an example of the types of things stored in cookies after pressing the "got it" button.

```
"wpcc=dismiss; username=<username>"
```

Here is an image of what is in local storage.
[Image of local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKj55.png)
The cookie banner will be on every page on the website so you will always have a chance to see it.
Cookies will not be stored on the user's computer unless they press the "got it" button.

Local storage will be used though to store the color of the background (It cycles through different hues to make a rainbow effect) that's what the rainbow key is.

Can someone let me know if i'm doing anything wrong and how I should be doing it or if this is all good

Comment: A bit aside, but don't store any part of the user credentials (like username) at client side.

Comment: @Teemu Sorry I should have mentioned that it is only used to display the user's username quickly without having to contact firebase the server.